# I can not make my Discord Bot send a message when variable is set to True

Tags: python, discord

I have two seperate Python files. On the first one I have my Discord Bot. The second one has some functions and when some certain event happens, it tells Discord Bot to send a message. At least that's what I'm trying to do. This is the first file:

```
import discord
import asyncio

client = discord.Client()
var1 = False

async def my_background_task():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    channel = client.get_channel(CHANNEL ID)

    global var1

    while var1 == True:
        await channel.send_message("Hey")
        var1 = False
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        
client.loop.create_task(my_background_task())
client.run(TOKEN)
```

And this is the second:

```
import new_test1

new_test1.var1 = True
```

The present situation is I get no messages from Discord Bot. While I expect to get a "Hey" each time I set var1 = True.

I think the problem is it never executes

```
new_test1.var1 = True
```

Comment: I've just tried this. Now I get "AttributeError: 'TextChannel' object has no attribute 'send_message'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, when the second file imports the first one, the bot starts working. This means the lines after `client.run(TOKEN)` will never be executed.

The solution is not to import the file. Instead, we can make the two communicate by writing and reading to/from a text file.

Example:
File2.py writes "Go!" to data.txt when needed.

File1.py reads data.txt in an infinite loop and when it reads "Go!", it prints "Hey!!". (It is important to clear data.txt after this, or else it will spam "Hey!!" because it will still read "Go!".)